# When i bind a domain with GAE I need to use Google Apps. Do it mean i will be charged after trial?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

when I sign in Google Apps, it says 'Google Apps for Business will expire in 31 days'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
As of 12/6/12 Google no longer offers the "free" edition.

[Changes to Google Apps for businesses](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2012/12/changes-to-google-apps-for-businesses.html)

You can, however, still create a new Apps account by going through the App Engine Admin Console

> If you create a new Apps account going through the App Engine Admin Console you'll still be able to create a Standard Apps account for free but you'll only be able to get 1 user per account rather than the 10 you get today.

[Google App Engine Group Discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/pVZfdeky-ow/TO1SmipM2Y0J)

---

**Original Response:**

There is a Google Apps free edition -- it's called **"Standard Edition"**. Everyday they make it harder and harder to find, though.

Here's the help article that discuses changing from Business to Standard:

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60229

> #### Steps to downgrade
>
> You can [downgrade](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60755) to Google Apps during the 30-day Google Apps for Business free trial by cancelling the trial. If you'd like to downgrade your Google Apps for Business subscription after the end of the free trial, the timing and financial aspects depend on your billing plan.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not like that what you are thinking, you can even signup for Google Apps for Free. It is a free version. You can signup into it with the following link.

http://www.google.com/intl/en_in/enterprise/apps/business/pricing.html

Even if you have already signed up for Google Apps for business you can degrade it to free version by navigating into your admin panel and follow the steps in the URL.

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60755